# Change db instances in ForestAdmin and Lumber

Tags: node.js, mattermost, forestadmin

As admin part I want to use ForestAdmin.

Also I am gonna use already existing database (Mattermost`s actually).

Everything was deployed to AWS (ForestAdmin and Mattermost).

Due to [tutorial](https://docs.forestadmin.com/documentation/getting-started/installation/install-with-lumber) I can install ForestAdmin via Lumber and connect it to existing db. Actually I have done this, do some playing with code to expand some functionalities.

The main question is: when I install ForestAdmin locally via Lumber - I point to my local instance of database and lumber generates code (models and CRUD). So also I can install ForestAdmin locally and point to Mattermost`s database on AWS. **BUT** can I somehow change which database I want to use - local or that one on AWS?

Maybe I explain this problem bad - so also I will try to rephrase with example of desired flow:

1. Mattermost with database already installed on AWS
2. ForestAdmin also installed via Lumber and connected to Mattermost`s db
3. I got local instance of Forestadmin and Mattermost, write some code, test it in local environment.
4. Push to repo, connect via ssh to AWS and pull changes which was made.
5. AWS instances works as local but with separate instances of db.

Or maybe there is some better way to push changes from local Forestadmin and pull it to AWS instance of Forestadmin?

Thanks for any help in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Yes you definitely can, you can use Forest environment for that :

https://docs.forestadmin.com/documentation/reference-guide/how-it-works/environments